# asp.net mvc 3 return a message from controller action ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question about Ajax form submit. Here is the code:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(true)]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactForm model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {                    
        return new EmptyResult();                    
    }
    else
    {
        string message = model.Name + " " + model.Telephone + " " + model.Email + " " + model.Address + " " + model.City + " " + model.ZipCode;

        //send it    

        return new EmptyResult();
     }
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PostSuccess() {
        $('.success-message').html("Thank you for your interested");
    }

    function PostFailure() {
        $('.success-message').html("Something went wrong... Make sure the required fields are filled out and in correct format");
    }
</script>
<div class="contact-form">
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "Info", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "PostFailure", OnSuccess = "PostSuccess" }))
{ 
    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, "Your name") 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "required" })<span class="required">*</span>
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, "Your email")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)<span class="required">*</span>
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Telephone, "Your phone")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Telephone)<span class="required">*</span>
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address, "Your address")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address)
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ZipCode, "Your zipcode")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ZipCode)
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, "Your city")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)
    </p>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" id="bContact">Send Message</button>
}

<div class="required">* Required Fields</div>
<div class="success-message">Output</div>
```

All I want is a appropriate message in "success-message" class, but the POST is always successful so I always get "Thank you for your interest."

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a appropriate message in "success-message" class, you must change code in your action.
Such as :

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(true)]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactForm model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            else
            {
                string message = model.Name + " " + model.Telephone + " " + model.Email + " " + model.Address + " " + model.City + " " + model.ZipCode;
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

and in success function, you put parameter in there .

```
function PostSuccess(data) {

        $('.success-message').html(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like for your form to be validated. That is, you'd like for the message in `PostFailure` to be displayed if the user made some invalid inputs, and to force the user to make corrections before running the code in the `else` statement of your controller. You haven't posted your model so I don't know if you are doing this, but for the form to validate you should use [Data Annotations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs).

For example, your model should contain:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required!")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

for the name field. You can change the message to be whatever you'd like, which allows for a message specific to `Name` rather than the generic one that you have, if you'd like.

Then in the view, you should include:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
```

And be sure to include:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

in your `web.config` file to enable client-side validation (assuming that you've included the jQuery validation libraries, but they're included by default in ASP.NET MVC3 projects).

Answer (score 0):

`OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` refers to if the AJAX call was made successfully or failed. From MSDN for [OnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx):

```
This function is called if the response status is not in the 200 range.
```

You can do the following to get OnFailure to run:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
```

But I would recommend that it would be better to change the success event to call a javascript function that would parse the results of the call.